# PDO Statement / Select / Big amount of columns

Tags: sql, pdo

I try to fetch a value from a sql table with a big amount of columns (around 200 not in a alphabetic order) - the first 5 columns were read correct, but than the var_dump says "null"

```
$stmt = $pdo->query("SELECT * FROM table WHERE BARCODE = '$code' LIMIT 1");
$row_percent = $stmt->fetch();
var_dump($row_percent['DE']);
```

The table looks like this
ID | BARCODE | AT | CH | AF | HG | XT | ZZ | DE | ES | 150 more columns ...etc

If i´m using

```
var_dump($row_percent[130]);
```

i get a value - but i can´t do it like this, as the number is variable

What i´m doing wrong?

Comment: maybe its getting null value,try to add and `BARCODE IS NOT NULL`

Comment: I tried it, but it is not working

Comment: Are you sure, that the column names are all caps? Are you sure, that you got any rows? what `var_dump($row_percent);` says? Are you sure, that the column 'DE' exists exactly with the same caps as you are trying to refer it? Are you sure, that PDOStatement::fetch() returns an associative array? Did you try PDO::FETCH_ASSOC as it's first parameter? Did you read the docs of the functions on php.net?

Comment: You made my day! The problem was that i had a space before the 'DE' - stupid mistake!